# Printing multiple slides on a single page in PowerPoint with C#

Tags: c#, powerpoint, ms-office

I made a printer application with C#. I have a powerpoint file. One setting used when printing a powerpoint file prints many slides in a single page. How can I do this with C#?
For example, 6 slides, 4 slides in one page etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to programatically set PPT's print options, the ppPrintOutputType enum lets you choose which of PPT's output types you get when you print.

Comment: What should I use if the same operations are performed within a pdf file

Comment: Afraid I can't help with that.  Sorry. I'd ask that as a new question and tag it with PDF instead of PowerPoint.